# Typing in radicals in Japanese

Tags: discussion

I've googled this and searched on quite a few websites but no luck. I've read replies here about this but it didn't work for me or didn't provide the information I'm looking for. Please read carefully as what I'm asking is very specific.

I want to find a way to type **radicals** on **their own**. I discuss radicals with other learners and I want to be able to type them up ***not*** copy/paste them. I want to type in the characters in all their various positions as radicals. I also want the blank boxes to appear when I want to talk about a radical which is one the left or the right side. I'd like to use keyboard shortcuts/keystroke combinations to achieve that.

I'm on Windows 10 and I use the Japanese IME.

Thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be your _input_ in order to type a radical with such a system, typing the pronunciation of the radical? Applying a shortcut/keystroke combination to an actual Kanji that contains the radical?

Comment: Also, please check [this question about typing chinese radicals](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5581/typing-chinese-radicals) at the Chinese Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @jarmanso7 Isn't that exactly what OP is asking? "What input should I give my IME so that I get the radicals?"

Comment: @Sweeper Are you assuming that it is possible to get the radicals, and moreover, in such a format that follows the requirements given by the OP with the Windows Japanese IME? I don't know this IME in depth, but I doubt so. I rather think that the OP is looking for a way to accomplish that result _regardless of the IME_, but I don't know

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the unicode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_radicals_in_Unicode

**Inserting Unicode characters**
To insert a Unicode character, type the character code, press ALT, and then press X. For example, to type a dollar symbol ($), type 0024, press ALT, and then press X. For more Unicode character codes, see Unicode character code charts by script.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for that.